# Unable to use signed cookies for cloudfront

Tags: cookies, amazon-cloudfront, signed

Im trying to use signed cookies for my cloudfront distribution.

Im using [cookie-signer](https://gist.github.com/mekza/b7cdc0858aa1dd22b016) to generate signed cookies.
And the below script to fetch a file from cloud front

```
import requests
cookies = {
'CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id': 'APKXXXXXXXXXXX',
'CloudFront-Policy': u'eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kNXRpdXV2ZjdodDlpLmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0L21lZGlhL3Byb2ZpbGVfcGljLmpwZyIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQ5Mjc2ODcwMH19fV19',
'CloudFront-Signature': u'ZVG-Pi7x~edJqERf99O9und0wYedB-SHMNKuHd4UpEDaPckYekGoAJ~q8tU0vQI4mS9odXITzAKl4v7tmfDjG1y9FmWaSxgf9h2jrssIk25Mswk3UXOV7wRNs9DiHpA3~D70qAWXGS9GVN4z3SvZ3xQv9bM1P50y2shNPlOCV4o5nAH56sYdvdJNjxSFxdoOUMuhxyrzf-Gv5fjNSzv2Dy43WY6rmpEMfh6L9Eb-2kcrS9p5rsK9MtAwpN8Frobt4bCuduQleb~DXZ~O~hoBGdO3RdyYWgMdTa~02PQl3st8eisBiH7XYy2GbOwPIN~M4m-UAs3ihL0ZWUjbkVDFCA__',
'Secure': 'True',
'HTTPOnly': 'True',

}
headers = {}

s = requests.Session()

res = s.get('http://XXXXXXX.cloudfront.net/media/profile_pic.jpg', 
headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
print res
print res.content
```

Output:

```
 <Response [403]>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>BBDBA8E7FEDA7759</RequestId><HostId>7Pt2/REdiugH5Te555/v004J6skQs9+ccncmXM74yHwPhQrSMJ9pavIj2QmPW6g2QsnnEYGxitc=</HostId></Error>
```

Added user to trusted signer for the cloudfront distribution and generated a key-pair-id for cloudfront.

Can someone help me with this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with the GitHub gist in your link. The expiration time needs to be provided in epoch seconds and the url passed in must be the full CloudFront url (e.g. `https://example.com/my/s3/object.png`)

```
import datetime
ex = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=expire_min)
c = create_signed_cookies(url, int(ex.strftime('%s')))
```

Your S3 bucket policy needs to allow GetObject from the CloudFront Origin Access Identity assigned to your CloudFront distribution.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Your key pair ID needs to refer to one you created like this (you must be signed in as the root account): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html#private-content-creating-cloudfront-key-pairs-procedure

Answer (score 1):

Your error is actually an S3 error, not a Cloudfront (CF) error. Did you create a bucket policy that gives `GetObject` access?

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

If you're using S3 as the origin in CF then you'll want to create an Origin Access Identity and make sure to give access to it in your S3 Bucket Policy. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-6)

If you're trying to serve the page using S3 static web hosting then I suggest either whitelisting Cloudfront IPs in your policy or adding an `Origin Custom Header` in CF such as `referer` and then looking for the header in your bucket policy. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)

As a sanity check, you might want to try to generate a signed URL using the AWS-CLI. (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/sign.html)